# how to create and use a ramdisk for gaming

Tags: windows-10, performance, 64-bit, gaming, ramdisk

I have a fairly decent spec PC which I use solely for gaming.

I have read that a ramdisk can significantly increase the FPS performance.

Can anyone help me in how to create a ramdisk, what files/drivers are required, whether I need to implement a drive image or what?

My PC spec is as follows:

```
OS = windows 10 64bit
CPU = AMD8350 (8 core)
Memory = 24gb DDR3 (2x4gb Mushkin Blackline 1600Mhz + 2x8gb Kingston Fury X 1600Mhz)
GPU = Sapphire NITRO AMD R9 380 Dual X (4gb DDR5)
HDD = 2 x 8GB + 500GB SSHD In RAID 0 stripe format (8GB SSD + 500GB Platter each)
```

I would be playing DAYZ Standalone on the STEAM platform.

Thank You for any help or directions that anyone can give me.

Comment: Where did you read that. Because it seems strange to me that a ramdisk would increase FPS. It might decrease loading times, and thus make the game faster. But atm I am lost to see how it would increase the framerate.

Comment: I am not sure how a ramdisk could increase FPS performance, what would you be using the ramdisk for since it only creates a virtual disk in RAM?

Answer (score 0):

[This link](https://www.reddit.com/r/dayz/comments/20e4sk/running_dayz_on_a_ram_disk/) has people that have tested it.  Everything I have read about it says you're not going to get more Frames Per Second by doing this and as the other 2 commenters said.  Now if you're talking about improving First Person Shooter performance, yes, this will help to minimize some stuttering while loading the large map from DAYZ.  I really doubt will you get any improvement with this if you have RAID 0'd SSD's.

As to why you were downvoted, it happens.  This is a community run forum and there could be a lot of reasons.  First, read the [Help>Asking](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) here, this is not a site about gaming.  Maybe if you left out DAYZ, I don't know. And you found a link on how to set it up, so perhaps it was not taking the time to do enough research or creating a generic profile.